# How to get an image to a pictureBox from a URL? (Windows Mobile)

Tags: c#, compact-framework

What and how is the best way to get an image from a URL when using the Compact Framework?

Something I found was this (made a function out of it):

```
    public Bitmap getImageFromUrl()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(this.SImageUrl);
        request.Timeout = 5000; // 5 seconds in milliseconds
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = 20000; // allow up to 20 seconds to elapse
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream ms = response.GetResponseStream();
        Bitmap imageFromUrl;
        using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int bytes = 0;
            byte[] temp = new byte[4096];
            while ((bytes = ms.Read(temp, 0, temp.Length)) != 0)
                ms2.Write(temp, 0, bytes);
            imageFromUrl = new Bitmap(ms2);
        }

        return imageFromUrl;

    }
```

But it won't show any images in the pictureBox.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you stepped through this code using a debugger? That would at least tell which line was failing.

Comment: I have stepped through it, but i can't see that any of these lines are failing.

The HttpWebResponse "response" is showing statuscode = ok (200),
The HttpWebResponse "response" is showing contentLength = 11922,
The HttpWebResponse "response" is showing ContentType = image/png,


The Bitmap "imageFromUrl" is showing Size = 256, 256  (correct),
The Bitmap "imageFromUrl" is showing m_bmpdata = null,
The Bitmap "imageFromUrl" is showing m_how = 1179689.

Comment: Oh... actually... the ms throwed exceptions:
'((System.Net.ContentLengthReadStream)ms).Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' long {System.NotSupportedException}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I now found something that works better, but thanks for an answer Steve Danner.
Here is my solution:

```
public Bitmap getImageFromURL(String sURL)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
        myRequest.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(myResponse.GetResponseStream());
        myResponse.Close();

        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: You're right, that is better.  You're cutting out all of the overhead of those other memorystreams.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a statically declared buffer of length 4096, when it gets to the end of the buffer, this line:

```
while ((bytes = ms.Read(temp, 0, temp.Length)) != 0)
```

is trying to read in 4096 bytes, when there are probably substantially less.  Change your loop to something like this.

```
using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int bytes = 0;            
            while (true)
            {
               int byteLen = ms.Length - ms.Position >= 4096 ? 4096 : ms.Length -  ms.Position;
               byte[] temp = new byte[byteLen];
               bytes = ms.Read(temp, 0, byteLen);
               ms2.Write(temp, 0, bytes);
               imageFromUrl = new Bitmap(ms2);
               if (ms.Position == ms.Length) break;
        }
```